# How to make a various clickable kivy image in a thumbnail gallery

Tags: python, kivy

Sup guys!. so I have this 'project' to make but... i have some troubles with kivy!. how i can make various images clicable with no text? i tired this

image like this image?

[image]

```
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(InterfaceManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.first = Button(text="First")
        self.first.bind(on_press=self.show_second)

        self.second = Image(source="parentaladvisory.jpg")
        self.second.bind(on_press=self.show_final)

        self.final = Label(text="Hello World")
        self.add_widget(self.first)

        #I wanted to make the "final" display two of more images.

    def show_second(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.second)

    def show_final(self, button):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(self.final)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return InterfaceManager(orientation='vertical')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Format your code, and also no `run` function for `MyApp`

Comment: Explain yourself better, you are not understood

Comment: You can set an image as the background of a `Button` using the `background_normal` property of the `Button`.  That basically gives you a clickable image.